# Bootstrap modal and using external URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a modal popup in which users can fill in a form or skip the form and continue to an external URL.

[image]

This is the code that opens the modal:

`<a class="btn btn-info btn-lg open-AddBookDialog" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-remote="http//:www.google.co.uk">Open Modal</a>`

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
            var partner_url = $(this).data('remote');
            $('#skip').attr('href', partner_url);
            alert(partner_url);
        });
```

The code here is attached to the button that opens the modal, this script pulls a URL from `data-remote` and sets it as the href of a button in my modal.

This URL is then given to the button you can see to the right (just take me... ).

In this example I've used: `http//:www.google.co.uk` but within the modal it acts strangely and I end up with `www.mysite.com/http;//www.google.co.uk` despite using an absolute path.

I am also using the same URL for after the form is submitted.

My question is, why in this set up is the modal not respecting the fact that the link used is an absolute link to an external URL?

Comment: I think it's because `http//:www.google.co.uk` should be `http://www.google.co.uk`

Comment: Or may be it needs to be `http://www.google.co.uk` and not `http;//www.google.co.uk`

Comment: @SGSVenkatesh > `A local link (link to the same web site) is specified with a relative URL (without http://www....).`

From [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

Comment: .... I feel like I've wasted the value time of you guys, I'd been looking at this for hours, perhaps I should've just taken a break :/

Comment: @SimonVisser I don't think that is the case from OP's description. The browser is treating the url as a path string rather than a url, which will be fixed once the url formation is fixed. Either by the way you mentioned or the one I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're typing your URL correctly?

You wrote `http//:www.google.co.uk` which is an invalid URL. It should start with `http://`